# screen character position control in scheme

Tags: position, scheme, character

Is there a scheme procedure that would facilitate printing a default string on the screen for possible editing (using left/right arrow keys) as the next input string to the program?  I guess I'm thinking in terms of a CLI version of a text box that is pre-populated with some default text.  Maybe someday I'll plan a GUI for this simple app, but not now.

If the answer is "no," then is there a scheme procedure to control the screen character position?  I could (possibly) emulate editing a default text string if I could control the character position horizontally and vertically.

If you have an answer please be somewhat detailed as I'm quite new with scheme.

thanks much!

Comment: There are readline (and/or clones) bindings available for some scheme implementations.

Comment: Or maybe run an external program like [`dialog`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog)